# How to set props use refs in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-native, ecmascript-6

who knows how change props in my component use refs in react js ?

```
<MyComponent
  ref={'input1'}
  name={'input1'}
  label={interestsName}
  disabled={ false}
  onChange={this.myFunction}/>
```

after onChange i call function with

```
myFunction =()=>{console.log(this.rews[input1].props.disable);}
```

May I change props use refs without use state? Because I have many '15' components such as this component. Thanks.

Comment: props are just arguments of a function call, you can't change them, at least is a bad pattern

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change props from child class, for more please refer to [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only).

For your functionality use you can use state to change value on the change event. And one more thing you should keep the logic of changing component properties should remain inside a component. This will help us to maintain different states for different components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
     disable: props.disabled
    };
  }

  myFunction() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }
}
```

You can iterate over the above component and it can be used for 15 times and different states can be managed for every element

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use ref in this case, you should use states to change your child props:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      disable: false,
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({ disable: true });
  }

  <MyComponent
    name="input1"
    label={interestsName}
    disabled={this.state.disable}
    onChange={this.onChange}
  />  
}
```

In `<MyComponent>` use `componentWillReceiveProps()` to detect new props value.

Comment: I use array with this component and if i can use state for this I change all components of array on one click.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem?